# Trying to round a value which results from 2 multiplied fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, numbers

In SQL Server, I am trying to round a value which results from 2 multiplied fields `t.hourlyRate` and `t.hours`. The sum is calculated as:

```
SUM(t.hours * t.hourlyRate) AS tot_cost
```

The results gives me values such `33.2330` or `51.6648` whereas I just want `33.2` or `51.7`.

I've just variants of cast/round etc to no avail - any ideas please

Comment: Are you using decimal or float data type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `cast()` the result like this

```
cast(sum(t.hours * t.hourlyRate) as decimal(10,1))
```

Comment: Thanks - this answered my query.

Answer (score 2):

Use `ROUND` function, *which starts with SQL Server 2008* , upto precision `1` as :

```
SELECT ROUND(33.2330, 1) AS RoundValue1,
       ROUND(51.6648, 1) AS RoundValue2;

RoundValue1    RoundValue2
-----------    -----------
   33.2           51.7
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2012 or later, then `FORMAT` is an option:

```
FORMAT(SUM(t.hours * t.hourlyRate), 'N1') AS tot_cost
```